# pixel wise softmax with crossentropy for multiclass segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a multiclass semantic segmentation model with 2
classes ( human, car). here is my modified implementation of unet architecture. I number of output channels to 3 (3 classes - human, car, background). How do i get pixel wise classification?
here are 2 examples from my ground truth masks.

i am using 1 channel for each object class ie.

- channel 1 for class=car
- channel 2 for class=background
- channel 3 for class=human

[image: class 1]
[image: class 2]

```
def conv_block(tensor, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', initializer="he_normal"):
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x


def deconv_block(tensor, residual, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', strides=(2, 2)):
    y = Conv2DTranspose(nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), strides=strides, padding=padding)(tensor)
    y = concatenate([y, residual], axis=3)
    y = conv_block(y, nfilters)
    return y

def Unet(img_height, img_width, nclasses=3, filters=64):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), name='image_input')
    conv1 = conv_block(input_layer, nfilters=filters)
    conv1_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = conv_block(conv1_out, nfilters=filters*2)
    conv2_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = conv_block(conv2_out, nfilters=filters*4)
    conv3_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = conv_block(conv3_out, nfilters=filters*8)
    conv4_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    conv4_out = Dropout(0.5)(conv4_out)
    conv5 = conv_block(conv4_out, nfilters=filters*16)
    conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    deconv6 = deconv_block(conv5, residual=conv4, nfilters=filters*8)
    deconv6 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv6)
    deconv7 = deconv_block(deconv6, residual=conv3, nfilters=filters*4)
    deconv7 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv7) 
    deconv8 = deconv_block(deconv7, residual=conv2, nfilters=filters*2)
    deconv9 = deconv_block(deconv8, residual=conv1, nfilters=filters)

    output_layer = Conv2D(filters=nclasses, kernel_size=(1, 1))(deconv9)
    output_layer = BatchNormalization()(output_layer)
    output_layer = Reshape((img_height*img_width, nclasses), input_shape=(img_height, img_width, nclasses))(output_layer)
    output_layer = Activation('softmax')(output_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='Unet')
    return model
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done, now backpropagate the network error with:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output_layer, labels=labels))   
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

You don't have to convert your ground truth into the one-hot format, sparse_softmax will dot it for you.

Comment: i reshaped my GT masks as (img_h * img_w , nclasses) to match the output dimensions of the model. i trained with categorical_crossentropy but the model doesnt seem to converge. will the traditional metric 'accuracy' be a good metric to monitor ?

Comment: The accuracy lonely can't be a good measure to see if the model is converged or not. If you want to check that your model works well or not, I suggest training your network with only one train image, with batch size 1. Then check it if your model can learn the label or not.

Comment: Is it possible to not use the tf.reduce_mean function so as to backpropagate errors to specific activations? i.e. have a pixelwise loss?